# Use arrayaccess with static class

Tags: php, arrays, static

how I can use array access with my static class? 
F.e. I like to execute next script:

```
class A {
   ...
}
A['p'] = 15;
echo isset(A['p']) ? A['p'] : 0;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your question is asking? It's very unclear to me.

Answer (score 12):

The [interface ArrayAccess](http://de.php.net/ArrayAccess) only works for objects.  There's nothing similar for static access.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your class a singleton class then you can access it as static class